# Simultaneously detect change in value within a 4 second period

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, timer

I have an event which returns a different integer from an api value roughly every 100 milliseconds.

I want to execute some code when the difference of the integer in the event is 20 or greater within any given 4 second period.

Here is the current event that returns the int value every 100 milliseconds

```cs
private void OnMarketUpdate(object sender, UpdateArgs<L1LsPriceData> e)
{
    var data = e.UpdateData;
    int = data.intValue;
}
```

I can't create a single timer to to check every 4 seconds due to the over lap, eg. 2 seconds after the timer has elapsed and 2 seconds into the next timer elapsing there might be a change of 20 or more but it will not be detected because it is with in 2 different calls.

If there was a way to run a 4 second timer every second at least to detect the change in the update event above that would be good enough but don't know how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You should look into the `StopWatch` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0

Comment: Would you be interested for an Rx ([Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive#a-brief-intro)) solution? Or you prefer to not add dependencies to your project?

Comment: Add a lastTrue datetime variable . Within onmarketupdated set that to the current time when your condition is true. Then in a timer tick you can check every second to see if lastTrue is within 4 seconds. I'm not clear whether you also need to set lastTrue to mindate or some such when you act but that seems likely.

Comment: Use utcnow for current time to avoid any system time or daylight savings oddities.

Answer (score 1):

Store the current date/time together with the values in a list and update the list to contain the last 4 seconds of data.

```cs
private List<(DateTime time, int value)> _lastValues = new();

private void OnMarketUpdate(object sender, UpdateArgs<L1LsPriceData> e)
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    // Keep only values of the last 4 seconds
    _lastValues = _lastValues
        .Where(x => (now - x.time) <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4))
        .ToList();

    var data = e.UpdateData;
    int value = data.intValue;
    _lastValues.Add((now, value)); // Add current value

    int min = _lastValues.Min(x => x.value);
    int max = _lastValues.Max(x => x.value);
    if (max - min >= 20) {
        // execute some code
    }
}
```

I am using [Tuple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) available in C# 7.0 and later. You could also use a `KeyValuePair<K,V>` instead.

I also used [C# 9.0: Target-typed New Expressions](https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2020/09/08/c-9-0-target-typed-new-expressions/)

Comment: How will this solution behave is case the time is adjusted system-wise? For example lets say that the time is adjusted from 23:59:59 to 23:00:00 due to the [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Comment: No idea. This kind of tricky date time edge cases are the speciality of Jon Skeet's [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/). But changed the code to use `UtcNow`. But since the internal `Ticks` are used, this might be of now relevance.

Comment: Instead of the `DateTime.UtcNow` you could consider using the `Environment.TickCount`, which AFAIK is not subject to system-wise clock adjustments. Or use a `Stopwatch`.